# Recursion behavior in Python vs C# - Strange results

Tags: c#, python, recursion

I'm an experienced programmer but new to Python, so I don't know if what I'm seeing here is behavior specific to Python that I'm unaware of. I normally program in C++ and C# so I've included code samples in both languages to demonstrate the different results.

What I'm doing is running a recursive search function, using a state structure to record results. In C# it behaves as expected, but in Python it seems to be (as far as I can tell), not differentiating between the state that exists in current/last recursive call. I'm aware of Python managing objects by reference (as in C#) - I'm taking a deepcopy of the object before passing it further into the search function.

First up the C# version and results:

```
class SimState
{
    public List<string> stateDescriptions = new List<string>();
    public SimState Clone()
    {
        return new SimState() {
            stateDescriptions = new List<string>(this.stateDescriptions)
        };            
    }
}
class Program
{
    public void search_recursive(SimState state,int move,int recurseDepth)
    {
        if (recurseDepth > 2)
            return;
        state.stateDescriptions.Add(move.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}", 
            recurseDepth,
            String.Join(",", state.stateDescriptions)));
        for(int n = 0;n < 2;n++)
        {
            var newState = state.Clone();
            this.search_recursive(newState, n + 1, recurseDepth + 1);
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var initialState = new SimState();
        new Program().search_recursive(initialState, 0, 0);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

And the results: This is what I'd expect to happen. It searches all combinations down to a max. depth of 2:

```
0: 0
1: 0,1
2: 0,1,1
2: 0,1,2  
1: 0,2
2: 0,2,1
2: 0,2,2
```

So far so good. Now, what I thought was an equivalent Python program:

```
import copy

class SimState:
    stateDescriptions = []

def search_recursive(state: SimState, move, recurseDepth):
    if(recurseDepth > 2):
        return
    state.stateDescriptions.append('{0}'.format(move))
    print('{0}: '.format(recurseDepth) +  ','.join(state.stateDescriptions))
    for n in range(2):
        newState = copy.deepcopy(state)
        search_recursive(newState,n + 1,recurseDepth + 1)

initialState = SimState()
search_recursive(initialState,0,0)
```

And the results:

```
0: 0
1: 0,1
2: 0,1,1
2: 0,1,1,2
1: 0,1,1,2,2
2: 0,1,1,2,2,1
2: 0,1,1,2,2,1,2
```

It seems as if Python is not aware of the fact that I'm passing in a completely new state (via the new deep-copied 'newState'), and instead updating the existing 'state' from the previous recursive call. I'm aware of the post on SO "["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)") but that seems to be referring specifically to default arguments, which are not in use here.

I'm using Python 3.6 from within Visual Studio 2017.

Am I missing something obvious? Thanks

Comment: You've just pointed me in the right direction. I thought my definition of stateDescriptions[] in the SimState class was the equivalent of declaring a member variable, but as you mentioned it's a static class attribute. I replaced it with an __init__ method and assigning self.stateDescriptions = [] and it now works as I'd expect. Thanks for the quick answer. re why did I use a class? That was just to provide a cut-down example based on the actual problem I'm trying to solve, where the SimState is far more complex.

Comment: Makes sense. Anyway, I went ahead and just added an answer. Note, Python is a rather dynamic language, and it's object model is a bit different than your typical statically-typed OOP language. For example, `self.stateDescriptions` will first check the instance namespace, and if it doesn't find it, it will check the class-namespace, and all the name-spaces in the MRO. But, you can actually *shadow* class-variables with instance variables. So, say you had a mix of *both* your original definition and the modified one, then you essentially create a useless class-variable that always gets shadowed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your class definition. What you've written in Python creates a *class variable*, perhaps coming from a C# background, one would say it creates a "static attribute". In any event, you need an *instance attribute*, like this:

```
In [2]: import copy
   ...:
   ...: class SimState:
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         self.stateDescriptions = []
   ...:
   ...: def search_recursive(state: SimState, move, recurseDepth):
   ...:     if(recurseDepth > 2):
   ...:         return
   ...:     state.stateDescriptions.append('{0}'.format(move))
   ...:     print('{0}: '.format(recurseDepth) +  ','.join(state.stateDescriptions))
   ...:     for n in range(2):
   ...:         newState = copy.deepcopy(state)
   ...:         search_recursive(newState,n + 1,recurseDepth + 1)
   ...:
   ...: initialState = SimState()
   ...: search_recursive(initialState,0,0)
   ...:
0: 0
1: 0,1
2: 0,1,1
2: 0,1,2
1: 0,2
2: 0,2,1
2: 0,2,2
```

Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "python manages objects by reference", but Python *does not support call-by-reference* semantics. Its semantics are similar to Java - except that Python is a pure-OOP language, there are no primitive types, and everything is an object (so, it would be like Java except *everything* is a reference type). This strategy is technically called [call by object sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing)

Comment: Thanks - I thought declaring something the way I had in a class would create a member variable which is obviously not correct. Updating to using __init__ and assigning at that point has resolved the problem.